# How to check for missing data between two tables with different primary keys and a mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables, New, Old, and Master. The New and Old tables are structured the same with two columns and the columns are a composite primary key.

The difference between them though is that in the New table, the same data could be in both columns but in the Old table that is not possible.

The Master table has all the data to map between the two tables.

The data would look like this:

New table

```
NewCarGroupID     NewCarID
------------------------------
Audi              Audi
Audi              Volkswagen
Toyota            Toyota
Toyota            Lexus
```

Old table

```
OldCarGroupID     OldCarID
------------------------------
OldAudiGroup      OldVolkswagen
OldToyotaGroup    OldLexus
OldToyotaGroup    OldDaihatsu
OldGMGroup        OldGMC
OldGMGroup        OldChevy
OldFordGroup      OldFord
```

Master table

```
NewCarID       OldCarID        OldCarGroupID     
----------------------------------------------
Audi           OldAudi         OldAudiGroup
Volkswagen     OldVolkswagen   OldVolkswagenGroup
Toyota         OldToyota       OldToyotaGroup
Lexus          OldLexus        OldLexusGroup
GMC            OldGMC          OldGMGroup
```

Given this table structure, how would I go about selecting any missing OldCarID data from the Old table when compared to the New table in a query as long as a NewCarID exists for a existing OldCarGroupID even if a record doesn't exist in the New table? This can be done with multiple transactions to update data given, but for a single query I'm not sure. What I would expect this to return:

```
NewCarID    OldCarID          OldCarGroupID 
---------------------------------------------
Toyota      OldDaihatsu       OldToyotaGroup
GMC         OldGMC            OldGMGroup
NULL        OldChevy          OldGMGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use where not exists

```
Select * 
b.NewCarID, a.OldCarID, b.OldCarGroupID 
from OldTable a
inner join MasterTable b on a.OldCarID = b.OldCarID        
where not exists(select 1 from NewTable c where c.NewCarID = b.NewCarID)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MT.NewCarID, OT.OldCarID, MT.OldCarGroupID 
 FROM old_table as OT, master_table as MT 
WHERE OT.OldCarID = MT.OldCarID AND     
 not exists(select 1 from new_table as NT where NT.NewCarID = 
 MT.NewCarID);
```

Comment: You should always describe your code context for both the current OP as well as for the future readers.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote in the correct way and It was my fault that I did not see my answer again, thank you to point out,which I will make sure that i do not make this mistake again.

Comment: Even now you can add description to your answer by editing your answer.

Comment: There's still time... [Including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably increase your chances of up-votes, not down-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.